# Do compilers provide default move assignment operators and move constructors?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Do compilers (let us use g++ as the specific example) provide a default move constructor and default move assignment operator when we write a class?

Compilers provide a default:

- Constructor (no arguments) unless another constructor with arguments is declared.
- Destructor (which presumably does nothing? - actually not quite, this question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837223/c-default-destructor), it calls the base class destructor)
- Copy Constructor unless we write our own
- Copy Assignment Operator unless we write our own

Will a compiler provide a default move constructor or move assignment operator.

Comment: @dyp I think I may have a misunderstanding here - what class can have a copy constructor only?

Comment: @dyp Ah of course - edited

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014 Slide 28.

Answer (score 6):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> **Implicitly-declared move constructor**
>
> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type
>   (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators
> - there are no user-declared move assignment operators
> - there are no user-declared destructors
>     (until C++14) the implicitly-declared move constructor is not defined as deleted due to conditions detailed in the next section
>
> then the compiler will declare a move constructor as a non-explicit
>   inline public member of its class with the signature T::T(T&&).
>
> A class can have multiple move constructors, e.g. both T::T(const T&&)
>   and T::T(T&&). If some user-defined move constructors are present, the
>   user may still force the generation of the implicitly declared move
>   constructor with the keyword default.

And according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_operator):

> **Implicitly-declared move assignment operator**
>
> If no user-defined move assignment operators are provided for a class
>   type (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors
> - there are no user-declared move constructors
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators
> - there are no user-declared destructors
>     (until C++14) the implicitly-declared move assignment operator would not be defined as deleted
>
> then the compiler will declare a move assignment operator as an inline
>   public member of its class with the signature T& T::operator=(T&&).
>
> A class can have multiple move assignment operators, e.g. both T&
>   T::operator=(const T&&) and T& T::operator=(T&&). If some user-defined
>   move assignment operators are present, the user may still force the
>   generation of the implicitly declared move assignment operator with
>   the keyword default.
>
> Because some assignment operator (move or copy) is always declared for
>   any class, the base class assignment operator is always hidden. If a
>   using-declaration is used to bring in the assignment operator from the
>   base class, and its argument type could be the same as the argument
>   type of the implicit assignment operator of the derived class, the
>   using-declaration is also hidden by the implicit declaration.